# Magento2 retain cart items

Tags: magento2

I would like to retain/restore cart items after order is placed & add them in cart for both Guest & Login user, how can I achieve this?

I am using Hosted Paypal, so when the user sees the reloaded frame, on refresh I want user to see the last items added in cart which got removed when user click on continue button of paypal.

Answer (score 0):

In your `events.xml` add new observer `sales_order_place_after`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_place_after">
        <observer name="refill_quote_items" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\DataAssignObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

in your observer file `app\code\Vendor\Module\Observer\DataAssignObserver.php`

```
<?php

namespace Venddor\Module\Observer;

class DataAssignObserver implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    protected $checkoutSession;
    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
    )
    {
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->checkoutSession->restoreQuote();

        return $this;
    }
}
```

I haven't tried this code, but logically it should be like this.